# How to link all transactions related to one policy number in blockchain

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, ethereumj

I am new to blockchain technology, excuse me if my question is not clear.

I want to expose a smart contract related to car insurance, that contain very high level of information.  Example below

```
contract Insurance {
        string fullName; // Full Name
        string policyNumber; // Say A123
        string status;  // ACTIVE
        uint totalCarsInsured; // Say he has 2 cars
        string hashOfDBInfo; // hash represents the database info
}
```

We published above information to ethereum public network.

My question is, when the customer sells one of his car, now totalCarsInsured is 1, that information will be updated in the back-end database, we generate a new hash code with that information and publish a new transaction to Ethereum network, how do we link these two transactions? Or how do we handle the scenarios where past information that can be referenced?

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe I don't understand your question right, but some thoughts on what I've understood:*

Тake as a basis а) DB Migrations b) GIT commits

##### Initialize the Database

Create SQL statements to create tables and insert initial data, this would be your, e.g. `1.sql` migration

##### Create a new customer

- take the previous SQL migration, e.g. `1.sql`
- get the hash of its content
- Create `2.sql` with that hash, as a comment, and all required `insert` statements to create the new user.
- Update the database
- Create the blockchain transaction to create a new customer - `hashOfDBInfo` would be the hash of `2.sql`

##### Update the customer

- again, take the prev SQL migration, e.g. `2.sql`
- get the hash of its content
- Create `3.sql` with that hash, as a comment, and all required `update` statements to update the new user.

```sql
-- prev: 0e7dffb08d259ce96af7fceaf30e8faa529efbb6
-- date: 2023-01-20 11:35

UPDATE Customers
SET totalCarsInsured = 1
WHERE CustomerID = 1;
```

- Update database
- Update blockchain with the new value of `totalCarsInsured`, and `hashOfDBInfo` would be the hash of `3.sql`

*... and so on.*

As a result, you have **linked** and **unmodifiable** migrations.

> Additionally, you could use the hash of the file in its name to quickly reference **the migration from `hashOfDBInfo`**